# Poi api XSSFWorkbook sheet cast EXCEPTION

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, apache-poi

```
package apsel5;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.poi.sl.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class A {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        FileInputStream f = new FileInputStream("D:\\LeadSuite.xlsx");
        XSSFWorkbook wbks = new XSSFWorkbook(f);
        Sheet s = (Sheet) wbks.getSheet("TestSteps"); 
        Iterator itr = s.iterator();
        while(itr.hasNext()){
            Row rowitr = (Row)itr.next();
            Iterator cellitr = rowitr.cellIterator();
            while(cellitr.hasNext()){
                Cell cell1= (Cell)cellitr.next();

                switch(cell1.getCellType()){
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                    System.out.println(cell1.getStringCellValue());
                    break;
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                    System.out.println(cell1.getNumericCellValue());
                   break;
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                    System.out.println(cell1.getBooleanCellValue());
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get an exception after running the above code:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet cannot be cast to
>   org.apache.poi.sl.usermodel.Sheet

Answer (score 3):

You imported the wrong version of `Sheet`. Simply turn

`import org.apache.poi.sl.usermodel.Sheet;`

into

**`import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;`**

that represents the **Excel** worksheet, and your code should work. No cast should be needed for `Sheet`, `Row` and `Cell`.

---

If you look at the `XSSFSheet` class definition, you can see that it implements `org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet`. On the other hand, the `org.apache.poi.sl.usermodel.Sheet` interface is related with **PowerPoint**; in fact, according to the Javadoc, it's the

> Common parent interface for `Slides`, `Notes` and `Masters`

So **`.ss.` = Excel** (XSSF), and **`.sl.` = PowerPoint** (XSLF). The fact that these two interfaces have the same name may actually be misleading.

Comment: You're welcome @Ranjith93. You can also mark the answer as correct if you want. Kind regards.